# Set item in ListView not clickable and save it to preference

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I need help from my code. Just to mention that I'm completely new in programming and android world so my code may look bad written.

I want to set particular items in List View not clickable and store that information for the next time I open app or that activity. Can I do it with Sharedpreference? This is only a part of my code but I hope that you get an idea.

Method for disabling specific view using Sharedpreference information about position. I don't know where to put this. Because if I put it inside onClick method then it need to be clicked on some item first but I want to set not clickable before clicking.

```
 for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
                    View disableView = getViewByPosition(preferences2.getInt("POSITION"+i, 7), list);
                    disableView.setOnClickListener(null);
                    disableView.setEnabled(false);
                }
```

Method for getting View by position

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
            return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
            return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
```

OnClick method of Dialog where I store position information.

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {



                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which){
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                if (((position + 1)*2)<=numberOfStars){
                                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flagImg);
                                imageView.setImageResource(flagImageId[position]);

                                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countryName);
                                textView.setText(countryNames[position]);

                                editor.putInt("FLAG" + position, flagImageId[position]);
                                editor.putString("NAME" + position, countryNames[position]);
                                editor.putInt("POSITION" + position, position);

                                editor.commit();

                                view.setOnClickListener(null);
                                view.setEnabled(false);



                            } else{

                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(UnlockFlagsActivity.this, "You dont have enough stars", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.show();
                                    break;
                                }
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Comment: In Itemclick event, based on the position, you can handle the response. if you want certain rows to be non-clickable, handle it in code accordingly. What issue are you facing with it ?

Comment: OK, but when I first click on item and fulfill the requirement then I want to permanently set not clickable to that item and store that information for future uses of app or activity